# Apply array of functions to dataframe

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe, apply

Suppose you have an array of functions.  Each function returns a `pandas.Series` object of the same indexing and size. Each function takes in the same input, the main dataframe `df`.

I'm looking for an output that has each of the series as a column of a resulting dataframe

Currently I have the following:

```
df_result = [f(df) for f in f_arr]
df_result = pd.DataFrame(df_result)
```

This takes a long time (there seems to be some overhead on the list operation) and the resulting dataframe is the transpose of what I need.  I feel like there should be a clean map/apply way to do this.

Comment: `pd.concat(df_result, axis=1)` will avoid getting the transpose.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: @EFT if you type your comment as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
 df_result = pd.concat(df_result, axis=1)
```

in place of the second line will avoid getting the transpose.